# Non finitely-generated subalgebra of a finitely-generated algebra

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, examples

Ok, I feel a little bit ashamed by my question.

This afternoon in the train, I looked for a counter-example:
— $k$ a field 
— $A$ a finitely generated $k$-algebra 
— $B$ a $k$-subalgebra of $A$ that is not finitely generated

Finally, I have found this: 
— $k$ any field
— $A=k[x,y]$
— $B=k[xy, xy^2, xy^3, \dots]$

(proof : exercise)

My questions are:

1) What is your usual counter-example ?
2) Under which conditions can we conclude that $B$ is f.g. ?
3) How would you interpret geometrically this counter-example ?

Comment: 2) For example, if $B$ is the invariant ring of $A$ under the action of a group $G$, and $A$ is a completely reducible $G$-module, then $B$ is f.g.. This is Hilbert's theorem. It is far from being an if-and-only-if, however, and it seems hard to construct non-f.g. invariant rings even without complete reducibility.

Comment: @nicojo, I see no need to start your question by "Ok, I feel a little bit ashamed by my question", there are a lot worse MO questions out there..

Comment: Although I'm sure this is no surprise, it might be worth adding that subalgebras of an algebra with a single generator are finitely generated (http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1957-008-05/S0002-9939-1957-0091273-0/S0002-9939-1957-0091273-0.pdf). So the case you have with 2 generators is best-possible in this sense.

Answer (score 17):

It is easy to make examples of such subrings. For example, take $A=k[x,y]$ and consider the subring

$$
B=k[x^a y^b  : 0\le \frac{b}{a}<\sqrt{2}].
$$Geometrically, $B$ is spanned by monomials whose exponent vectors lie below the line $y=\sqrt{2}x$.

I think your question is quite interesting in the setting where $B=A^G\subset A$ is the invariant ring of some group action on $A$ (or equivalently, on the space $X=\mbox{Spec }A$). In many cases this subalgebra is finitely generated, which allows one can define a quotient space $X/G$ by $Y=\mbox{Spec }A^G$  with many good properties. This happens for example if $G$ is finite or reductive. However, as shown by Nagata's famous counterexample to Hilbert's 14th problem, $A^G$ may be infinitely generated, so the problem of defining such quotients in general is subtle. (Nagata's construction is indeed very geometrical, but a bit too complicated to restate here).

Answer (score 12):

Dear Nicojo, since you now have many counter-examples, let me give you a situation where $B$ *is* finitely generated, in line with your question 2). I am going to adopt your notations with the important caveat that $k$ is a ring which needn't be a field .

**Theorem of Artin-Tate** Consider the inclusions of rings  $k \subset B  \subset A$ .  Suppose that $k$ is Noetherian, that $A$ is a finitely generated *algebra* over $k$ and that $A$ is a finitely generated *module* over $B$. Then $B$ is a finitely generated *algebra* over $k$.

You might interpret this as saying that when $B$ is  sufficiently close to $A$, finite generation is preserved.

You can find the proof in Atiyah-Macdonald, Proposition 7.8, page 81.
From this theorem you can then prove Zariski's result that an extension of fields that is finitely generated as an algebra is actually a finite-dimensional extension (Proposition 7.9 page 82 *loc.cit.*) and then  Hilbert's Nullstellensatz is literally an exercise: exercise 14, page 85 . So this result of Artin-Tate is really basic in commutative algebra and algebraic geometry, not surprisingly if you consider the authors (the Artin here is Emil, Mike's father.)

Answer (score 7):

With regards to your questions.

1)  Here's another example.  $k[y, xy, y/x, y/x^2, y/x^3, \dots]$.  The localization of this at the origin is a valuation ring (and this idea can be used to construct many other examples).

2+3)  If you are constructing examples of this type, many are constructed by gluing.  In other words, as pushouts of diagrams of affine schemes
$$ \{ X \leftarrow Z \rightarrow W \}. $$
where $Z \to X$ is a closed immersion and $Z \rightarrow W$ is arbitrary.  The condition you then want in (2) is for $Z \rightarrow W$ to be a finite map.  Some relevant references include *Ferrand*, "Conducteur, descente et pincement", MR2044495 (2005a:13016) and *Artin*, "Algebraization of Formal Moduli II: Existence of Modifications", MR0260747 (41 #5370)

For example, the ring $k[x, xy, xy^2, \dots]$ is the pushout of
$$ \{ \mathbb{A}^2 \leftarrow \text{coordinate-axis} \rightarrow \text{point} \}.$$
This gives a nice geometric interpretation, you just contracted a coordinate axis to a point, you can contract other schemes and get new examples.  Note the $Z \to W$ in this example is *not* finite.

My example in 1) is the pushout of

$$ \{ \mathbb{A}^2 \setminus{V(x)} \leftarrow \text{Spec } k[x,y,x^{-1}]/(y) \rightarrow \text{Spec } k[x] \}.$$

Where the maps are the obvious ones.
The $Z \rightarrow W$ map is not finite in this example either.

Comment: I think that your description corresponds actually to B=k[x, xy, x.y^2, x.y^3, ...].

Comment: nicojo, you are right, I misread it.  I'll fix it now.

Comment: One might also want to look at Karl's paper on glueing: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?pg1=IID&s1=773868&vfpref=html&r=11&mx-pid=2182775
